# Can't call functions of imported module

Tags: python, import, module, z3

I'm trying to use the z3 module in python.
I installed it using pip on windows.
However when i try to execute this code

```
from z3 import *

...

s = Solver()
s.add(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7)
s.model()
```

I get "NameError: name 'Solver' is not defined".

What I find odd is that importing does not generate an error message, so it should have worked, yet when I try to call different functions they seem to not exist.

Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Did you name your script `z3.py`? If so, rename it to something else.

Comment: A module can control what gets imported by `from ... import *` by populating its `__all__` attribute. `Solver` may not appear in `z3.__all__`. In general, `from ... import *` is a bad idea. Just use `import z3`, or be explicit about which names from `z3` you want to import (e.g., `from z3 import foo, bar, Solver`).

Comment: No, it is not called z3.py. I tried renaming it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @chepner if i try to explicitly import Solver it yields an import error. Does this mean something went wrong with the module installation?

Comment: What happens if you just use `import z3`, then try to use `z3.Solver`?

Comment: OK, I see the examples in the distribution all use `from z3 import *` (lovely). It sounds like you may have an installation problem.

Comment: @chepner AttributeError: module 'z3' has no attribute 'Solver'

Comment: @DocGurk: `import z3; print(z3)` should tell you which exact module or package gets imported.

Answer (score 4):

It was an installation Issue the module z3 is actually different from z3-solver (which is the one people in the examples use).

You can install it without Visual Studio Prompts like this:
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki/Using-Z3Py-on-Windows

Comment: In addition to this confusing situation (the other z3 installs boto as a dependency), it's possible to install z3-solver such that it'll import as a module but won't import classes or functions correctly. In that case, uninstalling and reinstalling it on pip worked for me.